# Why addthis facebook share always asks for captcha input

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, addthis

I'm trying to share in facebook using addthis and facebook always asks to input captcha.

Facebook reason to show captcha -

`A Link in Your Post Might Be Unsafe
It looks like your post contains a link that might be unsafe:
http://irpiedavajums.lv/assets
Please remove this link from your post or enter the security code below if you’re sure you want to include it.`

But i don't have this url in my share post.
Here is my share page [my page](http://www.irpiedavajums.lv/dvielis---sirsninas-forma/article/1283)

Comment: There are several references to /assets in your source code. Just fill in the security code. When enough people have the captcha will be removed

Comment: @WizKid Yeah, there is some /assets references, but i don't use it in share post. I'm using open graph to specify image. Therefore those images are omitted from post. I'm just wondering maybe there is issue in count of /assets images in my page and i need to merge my images in to one to fix this problem.